# When linking pages, does google give higher value to href="http://www.mydomain.com" than href="/"?

Tags: seo, hyperlink, search-engine

When linking pages, does google give higher value to `href="http://www.mydomain.com"` than `href="/"`?

I am wondering because I have heard that (for SEO) it is better to provide the full http address when linking to the sites homepage.

As I thought about it, I wondered why that would be. Would google really assign higher value to `href="http://www.mydomain.com"` instead of `href="/"`? They both mean the same thing.

Do you guys know or have any resources on this?

Comment: Question probably belongs on http://www.serverfault.com or http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so.

From Brin & Page, right at the beginning, they stated that they converted all URLs into absolute URLs before processing them:

> "The URLresolver reads the anchors file
>   and converts relative URLs into
>   absolute URLs and in turn into docIDs."

http://www7.scu.edu.au/1921/com1921.htm